# Difference between these two OpenSSL generation methods

Tags: qt, sockets, ssl, openssl, x509

I'm trying to create my own root CA.

Here's one way of generating a self-signed root key/certificate.

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -subj /CN=$1/countryName=UK/stateOrProvinceName=UK/organizationName=Me -keyout $1.key.pem -out $1.cert.pem
```

And here's another.

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out $1.key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -subj /CN=$1/countryName=UK/stateOrProvinceName=UK/organizationName=Me -key $1.key.pem -out $1.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 36500 -in $1.csr -signkey $1.key.pem -out $1.crt.pem
```

If I use the first certificate to create a client and server connection (using QSslSocket) then the connection is made OK. Trouble is the date on the certificate is 1975 and I can't use it to sign any others.

I constructed the second method to generate a root certificate with a vaid date, but the ssl socket connection fails with "unknown" error and no other clues. I checked that the right certificate *is* being used on both the client and server.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `-days 36500`, then the time wraps to year 1975:

```
    Validity
        Not Before: Oct 18 11:57:31 2011 GMT
        Not After : Aug 18 05:29:15 1975 GMT
```

Use smaller -days value. For example:

```
openssl req -x509 -days 3000 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -subj /CN=xx/countryName=UK/stateOrProvinceName=UK/organizationName=Me -keyout xx.key.pem -text -out xx.cert.pem
```

Then you should get valid day:

```
    Validity
        Not Before: Oct 18 12:01:17 2011 GMT
        Not After : Jan  4 12:01:17 2020 GMT
```

Comment: Ah, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=days+between+now+and+2038 ? I can't test this just now but it looks like this is it :-)